# Migrating Spring webmvc to Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am looking to convert my existing project which is build in Spring framework (4.3.8) in which i am using it below dependency

`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId><version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework</groupId><artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId><artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId> <version>1.11.3.RELEASE</version></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> <version>5.1.6.Final</version></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> <version>5.1.6.Final</version></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId> <version>5.1.6.Final</version></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.hibernate</groupId><artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> <version>5.4.1.Final</version></dependency>`

As I started migrating the project into spring boot version (2.7.5) as shown below, i am facing a lot of issue in the hibernate core. please assist which spring boot and spring data JPA version would be helpful to easliy convert to spring boot as per the existing spring web mvc framework.

`<parent><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId><version>2.7.5</version><relativePath /></parent>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId></dependency>`

`<dependency><groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId><artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId></dependency>`